# Schedule or trigger jobs in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to run a heavy test only once per day in Gitlab-ci. Is it possible schedule a job? Or is it possible to set it to manual and trigger it using the API?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to schedule a pipeline since GitLab 9.1, see:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html

Currently (i.e. with version 9.2) it can be configured as follows:

1. Navigate to your project's Pipelines ➔ Schedules and click the New Schedule button.
2. Fill in the form
3. Hit Save pipeline schedule for the changes to take effect.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am well aware of this. However, the linked page contains merely screenshots of how to configure it in the UI, which is why I didn't quote anything from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a patch up job, but you could use triggers with a **if** statement :

```
test_app:
  stage: test
  script:
  - if [ -n "${DO_TESTS}" ]; then make test; fi
```

And define the variable in the cron that make the call :

```
curl --request POST \
  --form token=TOKEN \
  --form ref=master \
  --form "variables[DO_TESTS]=true" \
  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/9/trigger/builds
```

See the doc : https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and will be improved in GitLab 11.6 (Dec. 22nd)

See [gitlab-org/gitlab-ce issue 20422](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20422):

> Currently all variables are shown in UI: 
>   http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html#pass-build-variables-to-a-trigger
>
> This is sometimes problematic, e.g. when you pass individual secrets to the build, which could not be placed in a protected variable and should not be visible to all team members.
>
> It can also be problematic even for some non-protected variables if they are unintentionally passed around in a screenshot/screen sharing.
>
> #### Proposal
>
> - Variable names will still be visible by default
> - Variables values will be censored by default with asterix `*******`
> - Variable values are toggle-able with a button
> - The button is only available to maintainers

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/uploads/1dc4f635096c16322801f3deeecf09ab/image.png]

Comment: I am new to this schedule in gitlab and I must ask, what is this variable in gitlab? In my case I want to execute one test at night and wanted to do this via this schedule but can't figure out what is this variable or class or that file. Where should I declare this variable and what should be the content of it? To be more precise I need to execute a specific maven command at a certain time.

Comment: @f.trajkovski The variable shown in this answer is just an example, to illustrate tto schedule job using variables without displaying their value.